Prove that if $Df(x)=\eta (x)Dg(x)$, then g is locally a composition of f and some function $\varphi$
I have this problem where I can't figure out the final step:
$f,g:U\subseteq\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}$ are $\mathscr{C}^1$ functions and $Df(x)\neq 0$ for all $x\in U$. Suppose that there is some function $\eta:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}$ such that $Df(x)=\eta (x)Dg(x)$ for all $x\in U$. We want to show that for every $a\in U$ there exists some open neighborhood $V$ of $a$ and some $\mathscr{C}^1$ function (let's say $\varphi$) on $f(V)\to\mathbb{R}$ such that $g=\varphi\circ f$
First we see that $Df(a)\in\mathbb{R}^n$ can be completed to a basis of $\mathbb{R}^n$: $$Df(a),f_2,\ldots,f_n$$ then we define $$F(x)=(f(x),f_2\cdot x,\ldots,f_n\cdot x)$$ and we notice that there is some neighborhood of $a$ such that $F$ is a diffeomorphism (we can do the same thing with $g$ and get a function $G$).
With this, we define $H=G\circ F^{-1}$ and write it by components: $$h_1(f(x),f_2\cdot x,\ldots,f_n\cdot x)=g(x)$$ in some neighborhood of $a$
I need to show that $h_1$ is independent of the choice $f_2,\ldots,f_n$ and we were told that by differentiating we should be able to conclude that, but I can't see how the partial derivatives $\frac{\partial h_1}{\partial f_j}$ would all be equal to zero for $j>2$ (and that would mean that $g=\tilde{h}\circ f$)
Any help is much appreciated
